# Unable to upload image on remote server(Heroku) with my flask app

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, runtime-error, attributeerror, flask-uploads

My app image upload works very well on localhost but when I deployed to Heroku, it gives me Attribute Error and Runtime Error. How do I solve this?

I remove the validators on the filefield in my form as suggested by some people here but it did not solve the problem

```
##########
#views.py
def add_post():
    form = AddPostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            filename = images.save(request.files['post_image'])
            url = images.url(filename)
            new_post = Post( form.post_title.data, 
                           form.post_description.data, 
                        current_user.id, form.is_public.data, 
                        filename, url, form.Share_location.data, 
                        form.home_delivery.data, form.share_date.data,
                        form.total_slot.data, form.slot_value.data, 
                        form.payable_amount.data, form.no_of_months.data, 
                        form.no_of_weeks.data, form.no_of_days.data, 
                        form.month_sub.data, form.week_sub.data, 
                        form.day__sub.data)

        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('New shared Item, {}, added!'.format(new_post.post_title), 
              'success')
        return redirect(url_for('posts.public_posts'))
    else:
        flash_errors(form)
        flash('ERROR! Share item was not added.', 'error')

return render_template('add_post.html', title='Add Item', form=form)

#############
 #__init__.py

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
if isfile(join('instance', 'flask_full.cfg')):
    app.config.from_pyfile('flask_full.cfg')
else:
    app.config.from_pyfile('flask.cfg')


app.config.from_pyfile('flask.cfg')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

images = UploadSet('images', IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, images)

#flask.cfg

UPLOADS_DEFAULT_DEST = TOP_LEVEL_DIR + '/project/static/img/'
UPLOADED_IMAGES_URL = 'https://bulkieshare.herokuapp.com/static/img/'

UPLOADED_IMAGES_DEST = TOP_LEVEL_DIR + '/project/static/img/'
UPLOADED_IMAGES_URL = 'https://bulkieshare.herokuapp.com/static/img/'
```

I want to successfully upload an image file to my remote database but I kept getting these error messages from Heroku.

```
#Here is the error message:
[2019-07-12 09:08:40 +0000] [16] [ERROR] Error handling request /add
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_uploads.py", 
line 327, in config
return current_app.upload_set_config[self.name]
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", 
line 347, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'upload_set_config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", 
line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", 
line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 261, in decorated_view
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/project/posts/views.py", line 68, in add_post
filename = images.save(request.files['post_image'])
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_uploads.py", 
line 414, in save
if not self.file_allowed(storage, basename):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_uploads.py", 
line 370, in file_allowed
return self.extension_allowed(extension(basename))
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_uploads.py", 
line 380, in extension_allowed
return ((ext in self.config.allow) or
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_uploads.py", 
line 329, in config
raise RuntimeError("cannot access configuration outside request")
RuntimeError: cannot access configuration outside request
10.31.79.212 - - [12/Jul/2019:09:08:40 +0000] "POST /add HTTP/1.1" 500 0 
"-" "-"
```

Comment: Are you using the same versions of all libraries and of Python in development and production? Are you defining your dependencies using a `Pipfile` or `requirements.txt`?

Comment: This isn't your immediate problem, but you should be aware of [Heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Instead of saving files locally you'll probably want to [use an off-site service like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).